# I want an image to appear when triggered by an "event" and nothing from other questions works

Tags: javascript, html, css, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to change the code in an old political version of a tic-tact-toe game from 2016. i made it when i was first started learning to code & never finished it(or the learning). i'm picking back up, so I came here trying to find out how to make an image appear when a game ends in a tie, but can only find how to do it when the mouse or buttons are clicked & nothing i change in the code(from those answers) worked. here's what i got, so far:

```
if(turn > 9 && gameOver == false){
                document.getElementById("result").innerText = "ELECTORAL TIE! CONGRESS ELECTS JEB BUSH";
                document.getElementById("rend").getContext("2d").drawImage(ttie, 0, 0);
          }
```

the words show up, but the picture doesn't. i have 3 files(html, js, css) in a folder with some images(one named ttie). i made a "div" named 'rend' in the html for the image, tried it on a canvas, and even moved the image outside of the body, but nothing worked besides making it happen "on a click". here are the html and css entries, so you know what i'm doing:

```
<h1 id="result"></h1>
<div id="rend">
           <img id="ttie" src="T-tie.png" width="200" hidden>
       </div>
```

css:

```
#rend {
position: relative;
float:right;
height: 440px;
width: 318px;
```

}

the `document.getElementById(rend).getContext("2d").drawImage(ttie, 0, 0);` attempt is just the last of the 20 things i tried to get the image to show up. removing ".getContext(2d)" doesnt work; changing the visibility when the game ends in a tie didnt work; none of them worked. seems like this should be easy. what am i missing? can i please get an answer specific to my question because i don't think i understand other answers to similar questions i've read or i'd have figured it out by now.

2nd question: is there anywhere you can learn this stuff in person for free? i've tried to intern, but i dont go to school. im out of work hurt now so its a great time to learn this stuff.

Comment: You've committed a double-no-no: Please only ask one question at a time, and do not ask for recommendations for off-site resources, books, etc.

Comment: Please, create a Fiddle,  it is hard to imagine all the things you describe without trying it out.

Comment: i'II Iook up what a fiddIe is and try it, TY. i wonder why aII them peopIe put it on hoId without giving any reaI advice, or instead of teIIing me how to do the fiddIe thing? they dont Iike you taIking bad about "the site", but they do things Iike that. how is it ever supposed to improve if you cant speak about probIems? for example, i think this website is seriously disfunctional because i tried to post the question about 8 times and it kept saying it was too specific & i should make it more general, so more people could use the answers; now, it gets put on hold for being to broad. nonsense

Comment: yea, jsfiddle, if that's what you were talking about, seems like a complete waste of time, but it might be worth it to try again if it'll save me time overall. made a profile, pasted the project into fiddle,& found out it wouldn't work there. fixed it, uploaded images to hosting site,& got the fiddle working after 30 minutes. all the while updating&saving every 3mins. then i changed the view(>settings >editor layout) & it started me over from the original version i copied from my files even though it said version 11 version changed but nothing saved. complete trash. i have to give up for today

Comment: omg just realized fiddle is an off-site resource. tomorrow, i will go find every mention of it on this site and flag them all

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a class to the image element like this:

```
 <h1 id="result"></h1>
    <div id="rend">
       <img id="ttie" src="T-tie.png" width="200" class="hidden">
   </div>
```

Then you add rules for 2 new classes hidden and visible where you set the visibility on visible or hidden:

```
#rend {
position: relative;
float:right;
height: 440px;
width: 318px;
}
.visible{
visibility:visible;
}
.hidden{
visibility:hidden;
}
```

After this you when the counter hits 10 you just remove the hidden class and add the visible class like this:

```
if(turn > 9 && gameOver == false){
            document.getElementById("result").innerText = "ELECTORAL TIE! CONGRESS ELECTS JEB BUSH";
            document.getElementById("rend").remove("hidden");
            document.getElementById("rend").add("visible");
      }
```

**EDITED:**
You can also use the css rules display:hidden to hide something and display:static to show something (if the element was static ofcourse before you hide it)

2ND question:
What works for me is to commit to a certain project. Try to build something you like, just experiment a little bit. And when you don't know how to build something, search it because Google always knows.

Comment: doesnt work. even tried with "rend" changed to "ttie" in the .js file to remove hidden and it is just visible all the time. it removes the initial hidden & makes it visible at the start of the game, then invisible when tie game happens & reversing it doesnt work for some reason

Comment: finally, i got it to work. i didnt realize i had to use .style in my .js file when referring to things in my .css file. i thought once i made a <link> to the stylesheet i was good with all that. in the css, i put 'visibility' in #ttie, then removed the 'hidden' from the <ttie> in my .html file & added document.getElementById("ttie").style.visibility="visible"; at the end of the 'if' statement in .js - I'll add my own answer showing it

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, here is how I got it to work;

html:

```
<h1 id="result"></h1>
<div id="rend">
            <img id="ttie" src="T-tie.png" width="200">
        </div>
```

css:

```
#rend {
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 440px;
width: 318px;
}

#ttie {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

js:

```
if(turn > 9 && gameOver == false){
        document.getElementById("result").innerText = "ELECTORAL TIE! CONGRESS ELECTS JEB BUSH";
        document.getElementById("ttie").style.visibility="visible";
  }
```

Comment: only problem now, is that i believe it's taking up that space even when hidden. i figured that out when i put the image outside of the <body> before and forgot until now. i really wanted different pictures to show up, depending on whether it was a tie or which player won. i thought i could just use an answer i got from this question and figure out the other two scenarios, but it doesnt look that way if it is using the space at all times. i should have asked the question differently, but hopefully somebody can get something from this. at least i learned about using the .style reference. thanks